# ant-contrib needed in 1.8.2 build.xml, but causes errors

Tags: eclipse, ant, ant-contrib

I find I need the following in *build.xml*:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${ant.library.dir}/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

in order to support the ant-contrib *<if> ... </if>* construct I'm using. However, Eclipse is very grumpy about this. With this section at the top of *build.xml*, everything works perfectly, whether from the command line outside of Eclipse or inside Eclipse, despite the grumpiness:

[image]

What "name" is in fact "undefined"? I would dearly like to understand what to do about this problem. Googling, I see others have had identical or similar problems, but no one's given a good answer, at least not that fits my situation.

Profuse thanks for any comments on this problem,

Russ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue and simple work around described here: http://www.mail-archive.com/user@ant.apache.org/msg39536.html

I confirmed that with the following build file:

```
<project default="test">

  <!-- Eclipse complains if you comment this out   -->
  <property name="dummy" value="dummy"/>

  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="C:/lib/ant-contrib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>

  <target name="test">
  </target>

</project>
```

If you don't have a property declaration before the taskdef, Eclipse complains.

Another work around I tried was to move the taskdef into a target. That worked too:

```
  <target name="test" depends="init">
  </target>

  <target name="init">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="C:/lib/ant-contrib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>
  </target>
```

Comment: Like magic, my friend! Thanks for this. (I wonder if I should hit Eclipse's Bugzilla with this one!?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the way I do it is just style or not, but what if you did something like creating a separate element for the classpath like:

```
<path id="ant.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <include name="ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

And then later on a line like @FailedDev suggested leveraging the `classpathref` attribute?:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" 
    classpathref="ant.classpath"/>
```

?

Or, I found one other thing which says to use `antlib.xml` instead of `antcontrib.properties` for ANT versions 1.6+?

**Edit:**

I'm having a hard time determining in which product this link fixed the issue, but if nothing else there are a couple snippets in this specific comment which may provide a suitable workaround for you -- although maybe they're what you're referring to above when you say

> no one's given a good answer, at least not that fits [your] solution.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=663236#c2

Comment: I'll experiment with this. I had already tried the antlib.xml thing too without success. I think this is an over-exuberance of Eclipse, but I sure want to fix it. Thanks! I'll check back with the results of experimentation.

Comment: @RussBateman I am using ant-contrib with ant 1.8.2 without any problems. Has to be Eclipse - specific problem.

Comment: The other thing I wanted to mention @RussBateman - and I don't have privs to leave comments yet otherwise I would have made it a comment on your question - is that I think the task/type that's undefined is `componentdef` (as opposed to that being a part of the message template). I believe there's also a way to just pull in the one extension you want (in your case the `if`), but I'll need to research that more.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, pulling in just for <if> might be useful to know although I guess the whole ant-contrib thing doesn't seem to weigh my build down at all. Hey, thanks for your help!

Comment: how about something like this:

    <taskdef name="if" classname="net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask">
        < ... >
    </taskdef>

i'll look to try that this afternoon as i have a need to pull in some tomcat tasks.